# Asynchrounous call from iOS automation test file using instruments

Tags: javascript, ios, ios-simulator, instruments

I am using the instruments app provided by iOS for automation of native iOS apps. The test scripts are written in a js file, so I was thinking if it is possible to make an AJAX call through this test script. Basically I want to keep polling in the test for some data that is coming from a URL call.

All I want to do is something like this:

```
try{
    var pinger = new new XMLHttpRequest();
    pinger.open("POST", "http://localhost/someurl/getData_ping"), true);
    pinger.send();
}catch(e){
    //returns null
}
```

And then I can check for the response and do whatever is required. But everytime it just goes to the catch block and gives the error as null.

Is there any way I can do it through the js file which acts as the test script? Also is there any information on where this js file is executed or what all it supports, because I am not able to find any such documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, if the class you are trying to use isn't in here

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/_index.html

or part of the ECMA specifications then you won't be able to use it. So you don't have any of the common Document Object Model or Browser Object Model classes such as `Document`, or `XMLHTTPRequest`. Any libraries you would like to use cannot depend on any of these objects, which eliminates most common JS libraries unfortunately. I was able to find an XML parsing library that manages to avoid this, it was very helpful for me https://code.google.com/p/marknote/

As for trying to make a post within your test, I think your only choice would be to use the `UIAHost.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout`
([see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIAutomation/Reference/UIAHostClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIAHost/performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout)) to either call curl or a python script or something that will take as arguments what you need to post. This method returns the output of the call if you needed to do a get as well.

As for your null error, it's a little odd, though I have gotten null or undefined errors before (which in my opinion should never happen). I notice you have the word `new` twice, maybe if you got rid of one of those you will get a XMLHttpRequest variable not found or something like that. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, the word new being there twice is a typing mistake(more of a copy paste mistake). I guess I will go with the curl for now as it seems to get the job done.